# Single Executable file

Tags: ide, executable

How to make single executable file ( not installation file) that run on every windows 7 . without needing any type of specific framework or platform .
    For example if i make c# application and try to run on another system, it require dot net framework. How can i get rid of this problem.
    Which Language or IDE i use to make independent executable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is exactly what you want,

but why not just write a c application that only makes use of Windows API and compile this one into an executable file?

IDE's compile it for you and you can run this *.exe on any computer you want.